# Transforming JSON data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

I have a website that pulls it's data from a JSON API. This is done using JSON.Net to translate the JSON into C# classes and that works great, and has done for months.

However, the developers of the API have released a new version of the API that changes the format of the data returned to me, and so this obviously now no longer fits into my C# classes.

What I am trying to establish is the best way to handle this. I could go and re-write my whole model, but this would mean massive changes to my whole site, so instead I am wondering if I can do some sort of transformation to get this new data format back into my current model. What I really need to know is what is the most efficient way to do this as I don't really want to slow things down too much by doing this transform.

Comment: please provide some code so people can help you better..

Answer (score 2):

If the adaption of the existing code is too expensive, you could:

- create a new model that fits the new API
- create a transform method to put the new model data into the existing model
- maybe you can overload the constructor of your existing model to do the transformation